# Difficulty with a Combinatorial Math problem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, binomial-theorem

I was doing this question from a national mathematical olympiad and although I couldn't solve it but I found something but don't know how to progress.

For a positive integer $N$, let $T(N)$ denote the number of arrangements of the
integers $1,2,\dots,N$ into a sequence $a_1,a_2\dots,a_n$ such that $a_i>a_{2i}$ for all $i$ with $1\le i<2i\le N$
and $a_i>a_{2i+1}$ for all $i$ with $1\le i<2i+1\le N$. For example, $T(3)$ is $2$, since the possible
arrangements are 321 and 312. If $K$ is the largest non-negative integer so that $2^K$ divides $T(2^n-1)$, show that $K=2^n-n-1$.

I was able to build this relationship. Is it correct? If yes how do I progress further? If not what is the explicit formula for $T(2^n-1)$?
$$T(2^n-1)=2^{2^{(n-2)}}\binom{2^n-2}{2^{n-1}-1}$$
but in the step-by-step solution, they gave this recurrent relation
$$T(2^n-1)=T(2^{n-1}-1)^2\binom{2^n-2}{2^{n-1}-1}$$

Comment: The second relation is $a_{i} > a_{2i} + 1$ and not $a_{i} > a_{2i + 1}$?

Comment: #matymangoo my bad

Comment: Can you explain how you built that relationship? And how does it differs from their solution? (Since presumably $ 2^{2^{n-2}} \neq T(2^{n-1} - 1 ) ^2$. $\quad$ FWIW I agree with their recurrent relation, which can be built by induction.

Comment: #Calvin Lin I didn't build the recurrent relation, it was given by the solutions. the way I got 2^2^(n-2) was just observing the binary. FYI I tested my equation and it works for all N from 7. It fails at n=3

Comment: #Calvin Lin, edit to my previous comment to Calvin Lin. I meant n=2 not n=3. and I meant Heap not binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationship is wrong; e.g. for $n = 2$ it suggests $T(3) = 4$, when as above the correct result is 2.

The recurrence relation is formed by considering each sequence $a_1, \dots, a_{2^n-1}$ as the array representation of a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). From the tree representation, we see that the number of possible heaps of size $2^n-1$ is equal to the number of ways to divide the numbers $1, \dots, 2^n-2$ between the left and right sub-trees, times the number of ways to arrange the numbers within the sub-trees.

This directly gives the quoted recurrence
$$T(2^n-1)=T(2^{n-1}-1)^2\binom{2^n-2}{2^{n-1}-1}.$$
The result then follows by induction, noting that $2^{2^n-1}$ is the largest power of two to divide $(2^n)!$.

You don't need to find the explicit formula for $T$, but from the recurrence, you can see that it's
$$T(2^n-1)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\binom{2^{i}-2}{2^{i-1}-1}^{2^{n-i}}.$$

Comment: #Adam but my relation is correct for 2^n-1 where n>=3 right?

Comment: No, it doesn't satisfy the recurrence; it's just wrong. @Hammock